# Error compiling ExamPeekableQueueImpl program

Tags: java

I got an error while compiling `ExamPeekableQueueImpl` program. It is showing me the error like interface expected and can't find symbol `ExamPeekableQueue`. Please help me to solve these problems

Comment: Please paste both interface and class source code

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation class `ExamPeekableQueueImpl` can not find interface `ExamPeekableQueue`. If interface is in another package, you need to import it in `ExamPeekableQueueImpl`.

Comment: Now it is showing me another error which states that could not find the main class:ExamPeekableQueueImpl

Comment: if you are trying to run `ExamPeekableQueueImpl` and it it does not contain `public static void main()` method then you will get this exception.

Comment: but my prog contains public static void main() method & still it is showing me the same error

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your interface is imported in the class if they are in different package.